# How to get a void function to work with another void function in C++?

Tags: c++

I put `'(RE)'` in `void F()`, but I approached one funny problem with my program. When I put `(RE)` in my void `F()`, my `void RE()` is coded above the `void F()`, how would the `void RE()` be able to know the `void F()`? Visual Studio wont let me run my program this way. I thought they were declared as void functions outside `main()` so I assumed those would work anywhere.

```
.
.
.
.
.
void F()
{
    if (nextChar() == 'a')
        match('a');
    else if (nextChar() == 'b')
        match('b');
    else if (nextChar() == 'c')
        match('c');
    else if (nextChar() == 'd')
        match('d');
    else if (nextChar() == 'a')
    {
        match('(');
        RE();      //HOW????
        match(')');
    }
}

void RE()
{
    if (nextChar() == 'a')
    {
        RE();
        RE();
    }
    else if (nextChar() == 'a')
    {
        RE();
        match('|');
        RE();
    }
    else if (nextChar() == 'a')
    {
        RE();
        match('*');
    }
    else if (nextChar() == 'a')
        F();                   //How????
}


int main()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Functions can have [declarations](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function#Function_declaration) and [definitions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function#Function_definition). To be able to call a function, all you code needs is to be able to see a declaration.

So, provide declarations for both `RE` and `F` and then define them.

```
void RE();
void F();

//RE and F definitions here.
```

Comment: Oh god.... Why did I bother to ask this.... My brain has been fizzling recently. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Put a **declaration** of `RE()` before `F()`:

```
void RE();

void F()
{
    ...
}

void RE() 
{
    ...
}
```